# Is there any settings needed for CloudFront infront of Lambda and API Gateway receive upload files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Flutter frontend that tries to upload image files to my AWS Lambda, going through CloudFront and AWS Gateway.  It returns the error in headers

`X-Cache: Error from CloudFront`

What I've tried: 
I've locally run the Lambda and tries the upload, and it's fine.
Every endpoint other than receiving files works just fine.

Comment: `X-Cache: Error from CloudFront` often means "upstream error observed by CloudFront" (i.e. the origin server returned a status code >= 400) rather than anything set incorrectly in CloudFront.  What's in the response body, and what's the HTTP status code?

Comment: apparently, I need to accept binary data by specifying the mimeType to receive at API Gateway. Now is working, thx for your help Michael.